# error '@react-native-community/geolocation doesn't seem to be linked'

Tags: react-native, geolocation

```
/// i used to commands:
/// npx expo install @react-native-community/geolocation
/// yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation

import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

const getCoordinates = () =>
  { 
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coordinates =>
    {
      console.log(coordinates);
    })
  }
```

** I want to use the geolocation api to get the latitude and longitude of the device location but i install the packadge from terminal but when i build it shows the "@react-native-community/geolocation" error **